# Spying / pressing buttons with C#

Tags: c#, .net

In BluePrism it is possible to spy buttons, fields etc. of any windows application and then click those buttons automatically. For example, if you look at the screenshot you can see the attributes of the calculator's button "1" as spied in the Win32-mode (there are also HTML-, Accessibility-, Region- and UI Automation-modes) by which BluePrism will be able to identify and click the according button. Furthermore, BluePrim is compatible with C# and I wonder whether (and how) I could also **get those attributes via C# instead or at least use the spied attributes** as can be seen on the screenshot to **press the same button with C#** instead?

**EDIT:**

It would be highly appreciated if someone could provide the C# code for pressing the calculator's button "1" to get me started (I'm a C# newbie :-) Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You do not need C# for that, you can just use a Reader stage and action `Get AA Attribute` or `Get Window Attribute`.

[image]

**EDIT:**

But if you really want to do it using .NET only, have a look at [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview) or [Active Accessibility Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-and-microsoft-active-accessibility) (older one)

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/invoke-a-control-using-ui-automation) seems like a nice example.

You will also find a tool called [Inspect.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/inspect-objects) very handy to spy elements without using BP. This

Comment: Thank you, Marek, but I don't want to use BluePrism (or just for spying if there is no other way), but to press the button / write the whole Robot with /in C# instead.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, those links are very interesting, upvoted your answer (still hoping for a code example :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Application Model that you just spied, put it in a navigate stage in your object, then select Click Mouse Centre as the action. This will result in the button you have spied being clicked.  Generally, to use Sendkeys is with C# syntax, i.e. use the root element (root element and top of list in Application Modeller tree) and select Global SendKeys as the action inside a navigate stage. In the Text input field you can enter your C# sendkey code, like for example for Ctrl + Alt + Delete use:  "^%{DELETE}".  I think this is what you may be looking for?  Otherwise, if I understand correctly, you might be looking to use a C# code-stage inside BP to pass sendkeys to an application attached to a BP process, which would possibly involve referencing each and every attribute of the host application in C# and then using (for example) the C# Enum properties of each keyboard key, etc... this would be a massively redundant exercise since BP already provides the functionality inside the navigate stage as explained above.

Comment: Thank you, Badda_Bing, but I don't want to use BluePrism (or just for spying if there is no other way) because except for the spying functionality I don't see the value added by BluePrism. So if possible, I want to press the button / write the whole Robot with /in C# instead. I have deleted the BluePrism- and RPA-tags in my original question in the meantime since this seems to have created confusion.

Comment: No worries, I get you now. Yeah, this should probably go to the C# .NET section. Good luck!